# Filling in a form located in a new page with selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating simple web automation using JavaScript and selenium for homework purposes. 
The purpose of the exercise is really simple, click on a link and fill a web form in the new page. 
The problem is that I'm not able to fill this form even though I'm able to locate the web element correctly ( I think ).

I tried to use both the Xpath and CSS selectors to locate the web element.

```
const driver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

const form = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Form Authentication")).click;

const username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div/input[@id = "username"]")).sendKeys("some text");


driver.get(url);
```

The expected result should be the form Username/password filled with some text. 
no errors show up, just no action,

Comment: I'm sorry, I've messed up with code formatting :/

Comment: Clicking the "Form Authentication" link has a JavaScript logic error. You forgot the `()` after the word "click".

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, very silly error. I've fixed and added parenthesis now, thank you for your Hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Please replace below line of code:

```
const username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div/input[@id = "username"]")).sendKeys("some text");
```

with this line:

```
const username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div/input[@id = 'username']")).sendKeys("some text");
```

Since you are using double quotes inside double quotes, it must be giving you error.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This should nail the OP.

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB :) What is meant by OP though?

Comment: Originally, OP is the short form of Operator which refers to the user who asked the question. But these days the new contributors refers to different things by the term OP :)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your hint. Anyway, it's not working yet. It looks like as soon the automation goes on a new page it's not able anymore to locate web elements. I got this error NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"XPath","selector":"//form/div/div/input[@id = 'username']"}. I've checke hundreds of times and the Xpath it is correct 100%...

Comment: @CarmineLentini Since you are sure that the xpath is correct, i doubt the element is not present when you are trying to search for it. Please try to use explicit wait while searching for this element.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your help, apparently, I've managed to go through by adding a window handling method in my code. Now the script switch from a page to another without any problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of problems with this code. I'm not sure what the `url` variable holds at runtime, but I suspect it holds the URL to the login page. You want to go to the URL first, then fill in fields.

```
const driver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

driver.get(url);
```

Next, you need to make sure you are calling methods in JavaScript correctly.

```
const form = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Form Authentication")).click;
```

This line of code assigned a reference to the `click` function to the `form` variable. I don't think this is what you want. You want to click the link:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Form Authentication")).click();
```

Next, you are improperly nesting double quotes:

```
const username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/div/div/input[@id = 'username']")).sendKeys("some text");
```

Use single quotes around `@id = 'username'`.

Furthermore, the id attribute in HTML is already inherently unique. You can simplify your last XPATH expression to:

```
By.xpath("//input[@id = 'username']")
```

You are also missing a step. After typing in the username and password, you need to submit the form, usually by clicking on a submit button.

Comment: Thank you for your precious help. I'm sorry for the very ugly code, I'm just learning JavaScript so I'm not oiled yet. Anyway, I've made the modification you suggested and added a window handling method. Now it looks like everything works fine :)